# PHP Замена строк в файлах на return из функции

Tags: php

Сделал на сайт поддержку тем. Выглядит так: темы хранятся в текстовых файлах, а в них есть вставки типа {SITE-TITLE}, которые я подменяю из массива $array['{SITE-TITLE}']= *и вывожу на экран (циклом ключи подменяю значениями)
Все хорошо, но что если {SITE-TITLE} нет в теме? Замена и хранение лишнего значения в массиве не хорошо. Тем более, когда это что-то типа $array['{MENU}']=menu_do(); где функция выдает приличное количество данных, получается если в теме нет {MENU}, то функция будет все-равно вызывается и жрать память, при том что она вообще не нужна.
Уже битый час ломаю голову как сделать так что бы не объявлять лишних переменных (вызывать функции) если их нет в теме, при этом все "переменные тем" (вида {**}) где-то были указаны в отдельном файле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну а что мешает перед выполнением `$array['{MENU}']=menu_do();` поставить условие?

Вот, скажем, список этих вставок:

```
$array = array(
    '{SITE-TITLE}' => 'title_do',
    '{MENU}' => 'menu_do',
    '{ETC}' => 'etc_do',
    );
```

А вот `haystack`, в котором надо эти «вставки» заменить:

```
$haystack = file_get_contents('some-template-file.txt');
```

Тогда вот цикл, в котором будет происходить получение этих самих значений:

```
foreach ($array as $entry => $value)
    {
    if (strpos($haystack, $entry) !== false)
        {
        $array[$entry] = call_user_func($value);
        } else
        {
        unset($array[$entry]);
        }
    }
```

Ненужные вставки удаляются, а для нужных получается значение через вызов функции. После этого загоняешь в еще один цикл, в котором производишь замену `$entry` на `$value`, хотя это можно сделать прямо при получении значения.
Что я недопонял в проблеме?

Comment: call_user_func то что нужно, ступил) спасибо большое!

Comment: другой вопрос: а если в $array хранятся не только имена функций, но и просто текст например. как различить, функция ли это?

Comment: Есть такая ф-ция для проверки: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-callable.php

Comment: То есть, цикл превратится в:

    foreach ($array as $entry => $value)
        {
        if (strpos($haystack, $entry) !== false)
            {
            if (is_callable($value))
                $array[$entry] = call_user_func($value);
                else
                $array[$entry] = $value;
            } else
            {
            unset($array[$entry]);
            }
        }

Comment: уже разобрался но использовал function_exist. чем от is_callable отличается?

Comment: Тем что `$value` может быть не просто функцией, а методом:

    $value = array($some_object, 'method_of_some_object');
    function_exists($value); // -> false
    is_callable($value); // -> true

Еще эта строка может ссылаться на ф-цию постороннего пространства имен (не уверен, что в этом случае вернет `function_exists`, но is_callable точно не ошибется).

Ну и еще анонимные функции появились в PHP 5.3. Например, так:

    $value = function() { return 'Aloha'; }
    function_exists($value); // -> E_WARNING
    is_callable($value); // -> true

Но в твоем случае и `function_exist` прокатит.

Comment: Да и сам язык говорит, что нужно не узнать, существует ли такая функция, а проверить, можно ли $ЭТО вызвать, как функцию.
В любом случае, если ты собираешься выполнить `call_user_func` или `call_user_func_array`, надо делать проверку на то, что $ЭТО можно вызвать, а не просто узнать, объявлена ли функция с 'таким_именем'.